# Traducir correo de pregunta cerrada: Your question has been closed

Tags: soporte, traducciones, cierre-de-preguntas

Me llegó un correo que la pregunta estaba cerrada, le respondí al robot de abajo pero no tuve respuesta... El tema es que el título estaba en inglés.

> ##### Your question has been closed
>
> [image: logo]
> **This question is off-topic.** It is closed and not accepting answers. [image: construcción]
> **Question:** Les aconsejo que no usen Laravel
> **Feedback:**
> Editar pregunta
> **What should I do next?**
>
> - **Read the *comments*.** The community provided specific feedback about why your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow Meta en español.
> - **Review on-topic guidelines for Stack Overflow Meta en español.** Determine if your question is *on-topic* for this community.
> - **If your question is on-topic, edit it.** After it has been sufficiently edited, the question will become visible to the public.
> - **Submit your edits.** Edits will be reviewed by trusted community members. If approved, the question will become visible to the public.
>   [image: robot] Gracias por tus contribuciones. Estamos encantados de que estés aquí.
>   Estás recibiendo este mensaje porque your Stack Overflow Meta en español activity triggered this tip or reminder.
>   Stack Overflow, *110 William Street*, 28th Floor, New York, NY 10038

No es que no me guste en inglés pero sí estaría bien una traducción al menos en el título.

También vi la dirección de correo, ¿Se puede traducir también?

> `Stack Overflow<do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email>`

---

Cuando voy a *Transifex* y luego intento traducirlo, ocurre un error, doy click pero no vuelve a la misma pantalla:

> You can't propose new suggestions because you're not logged in.

[image: transifex]

> 302 Found

Comment: Cuando se termine de traducir pueden cerrarme alguna pregunta que esté mal a ver si llega el correo.

Comment: Todo está en https://es.traducir.win. Ejemplo: [The community provided...](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=The%20community%20provided)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Ya lo encontré, era sensible a mayúsculas.

Comment: No pude: `You can't propose new suggestions because you're not logged in. Click here to log in`

Comment: Podés iniciar sesión con tu cuenta de StackExchange sin problema.

Comment: @padaleiana Cuando le doy click a `Click here` vuelve a lo mismo, no ocurre nada.

Comment: ¿Y en el enlace de [Login!](https://es.traducir.win/login) de la barra de navegación?

Comment: @padaleiana Con eso me inicia bien la sesión, solo que cuando voy a traducir aparece como que no estoy iniciado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que he traducido todas las cadenas que aparecen el el correo que indicas. Habrá que esperar a que las traducciones se integren en el sistema y espero que ya aparezca el correo completamente en español.

Espero que no se me haya escapado ninguna :)

Comment: ¿Se puede saber el tiempo promedio de integrado?

Comment: arteze no estoy muy seguro,creo recordar que se hace una o dos veces al dia. @G3rv4 es el experto

Comment: Las traducciones se mandan a transifex cada 10 minutos... pero sólo quedan aplicadas al sistema una vez que alguien hace deploy de una nueva versión de Stack Overflow. Eso depende del equipo de desarrollo (generalmente, si no es feriado en estados unidos, pasa un par de veces por día, pero no hay garantías, depende lo que tenga sentido)

Comment: @arteze lo que dice g3rv4 :)

Comment: @g3rv4 Tiene sentido, de lo contrario tendrían que usar `traducir.win` como sitio externo, es mejor como es ahora.